# How to snap polygons within a large polygon hole

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, snapping

I'm trying to perform a snap operation to fill the white holes and remove the intersections made by a previous shapely simplify operation. Here's one example to the occurrence:

[image: The full shape overview]

[image: The white holes made by the simplification]

There is the code I am running:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

from shapely import geometry

POLYS_ROOT_LST = json.load(open("geometries_list.json", "r"))


def create_feature_collection():
    geojson_features = []
    last_shapes = []
    next_shapes = []
    for idx, shapes in enumerate(POLYS_ROOT_LST):
        for shp in shapes:
            shp = geometry.shape(shp)
            medium_point_dist = (shp.length / len(shp.exterior.coords))
            simplify_tolerance = medium_point_dist * 1.2
            shp = shp.simplify(simplify_tolerance)

            # for last_shp in last_shapes:
            #     if shp.within(last_shp):
            #         shp = snap(shp, last_shp, 0.01)
            #         break

            geojson_features.append({
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": geometry.mapping(shp),
            })

            next_shapes.append(shp)

        last_shapes = next_shapes
        next_shapes = []

    return {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "name": "Teste",
        "features": geojson_features
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    output = Path(__file__).parent / f"test.geojson"
    output.write_text(json.dumps(create_feature_collection()))
```

To download the geometries here is a link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GOp2v2SqRVG1t8D1G38GC-nO5TJlBKM3/view?usp=sharing

I am using QGIS for the GeoJSON view.